# Subscribe to a observable not working in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm trying to see if i can subscribe to a variable of type `observable`. when i bind input with `[(ngModel)]` the changes don't seem to trigger.

**Code:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'alert',
  template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" />'
})

export class alertComponent {
  default:String: 'testValue';
  test = Observable.of(this.default).subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x); // only logs for first time
  });
}
```

Comment: what is `testValue ` here?

Comment: @PardeepJain you can check the edit hope its more clear

Comment: Ohh Get it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

RxJS 6 and above

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

of("testValue").subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x)
})
```

Refer [Could not use Observable.of in RxJs 6 and Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220854/could-not-use-observable-of-in-rxjs-6-and-angular-6)

Comment: i use 5.5 version of rxjs

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Comment: able to import `of` but `of("testValue")` you got to assign else it wont compile in first place. it fires only once.

Answer (score 0):

Observable.of only triggers once. And this is why it is working the first time for you.

If you want to trigger some action you could directly bind it to the ngModelChange event rather than converting it to an observable and subscribing to it ?

You may as well be interested in this question
[How can I make an input observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500047/how-can-i-make-an-input-observable)

Comment: yes that seem to be one way i agree, not sure if there is better way just like we do it in angular.js/knockout.js .

Comment: You can refer to the question tagged that may interest you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your modelvalue as a subscribeable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'alert',
  template: `
    <input type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="myValue"
        (ngModelChange)="myValue$.next($event)"
        (blur)="touched$.next($event)"
/>
    `
})

export class alertComponent {
  default:String: 'testValue';
  myValue: string;
  myValue$ = new Subject<string>();
  touched$ = new Subject<any>();

}
```

I added the handler on the blur event just to show that you can use this on any type of event.

Another way to operate on any type of event is the rxjs [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) method.

In case you never seen the "$" suffix: it is a popular naming convention to add it to anything subscribable.